# Correct way to extend AbstractUser in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, authorization, django-authentication

I'm trying to integrate two django apps where each had their individual auths working. To do that, I'm trying to subclass AbstractUser instead of User. I'm following the [PyBB docs](https://pybbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customuser.html) and [Django#substituting_custom_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). I've removed all migration files in all my apps apart from their individual **init**.py (including the migrations from the PyBB library sitting in my site-packages). I've also changed the Mysql database to a blank one to start afresh and I'm trying to subclass AbstractUser as shown below.

My Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.db import models
class Student_User(models.Model):
    """
    Table to store accounts
    """
    su_student = models.OneToOneField(AbstractUser)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'su_student'

    su_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_column='su_type', default=0)
    su_access = models.TextField(db_column='su_access', default='')
    su_packs = models.TextField(db_column='su_packs', default='')

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.su_student)
```

My settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.Student_User"
PYBB_PROFILE_RELATED_NAME = 'pybb_profile'
```

When running makemigrations for my primary app, I get this error:

```
app.Student_User.su_student: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'AbstractUser', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

How do I achieve what I am trying to do here?

PS: The app was working fine with onetoone with User without username_field or required_field.

PPS: I just checked the AbstractUser model in my contrib.auth.models and it has `class Meta: abstract = True`. Ok so its abstract, still, how do I resolve this? I just need one login, currently, two parts of my site, although connected through urls, ask for seperate logins and dont detect each others logins. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a one-to-one relationship with an abstract model; by definition, an abstract model is never actually instantiated.

AbstractUser is supposed to be *inherited*. Your structure should be:

```
class Student_User(AbstractUser):
    ...
```